# BringTextView's text in the next line

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I am having two TextView in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. If the second Text-view exceeds a particular length it comes below the same Text-view instead of adding as a next line. How can I bring the seconds Text-view's text in the next line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample text1 Sample text1 Sample text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample text2 Sample text2 Sample text2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:orientation="vertical"` to ur linearlayout

Comment: try  `android:maxLines="2"` to your `TextView`

Comment: hmm... maybe u want to horizontal in short text and vertical when long?

Comment: @prabhakaran. Thanks for the answer, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on text you give,either give enter at the end of your first text or use horizontal scrolling or change the orientation vertical.

Comment: I can't use vertical orientation. I need that to come in the next line.

Comment: give the enter at the end of your first text may be it will work

Comment: i think you should use relative layout and set layout using ids as per your requirement..

Comment: take relative layout and put your both textviews inside it and use android:layout_below="@+id/firsttext" property in your second textview

Comment: I want the second TextView text in the next line only if the text exceeds the limit.

Comment: Add this property may be it will work android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 0):

In your second textView Use like this:

XML:

```
<TextView
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="@string/userprofile_confpsw"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

in values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="userprofile_confpsw">"Conform New \n Password:"</string>
```

Conform New will display in Line-1 and Password appears in line-2.

Comment: The text is not static. Its dynamic. And This solution is not working.